# xcodebuild raises libSwiftCore error

Tags: ios, xcodebuild

Im trying to build my application with xcode8 iOS 10 for simulator and i'm baffled by this error. It builds for release, just fine, however, it has a hard time building for simulator. I currently have both Objective-c and swift files in my source. Has anyone see this error before?

`libswiftCore.dylib couldn't be copied`

Here is the console log:

```
13:42:35 Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib to /Users/myUser/dir/artifacts/Debug-iphonesimulator/myApp.app/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib
13:42:35 Probing signature of /Users/myUser/dir/artifacts/Debug-iphonesimulator/myApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
13:42:35   /usr/bin/codesign '-r-' '--display' '/Users/myUser/dir/artifacts/Debug-iphonesimulator/myApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
13:42:35 error: "libswiftCore.dylib" couldn't be copied to "(A Document Being Saved By xcodebuild)".
13:42:35 
13:42:36 ** BUILD FAILED **
13:42:36 
13:42:36 
13:42:36 The following build commands failed:
13:42:36     CopySwiftLibs /Users/myUser/dir/artifacts/Debug-iphonesimulator/myApp.app
13:42:36 (1 failure)
13:42:36 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
13:42:39 Archiving artifacts
13:45:06 Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 10):

I get this same error when I've run low on disk space.  Try moving the project to another drive, clean the project, and re-build.